# How to call a batch file with a flag from within a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script that needs to call other batch scripts that need a flag to run successfully.

```
:adobe_install
    echo 1. Adobe Reader & echo 2. Adobe Flash Player & echo 3. Adobe Acrobat
    set /p choice="What would you like to install[1-3]: "
    if %choice%==1 call "%adobe_path%\adobe.bat"
    rem if %choice%==2 call "%cd%\scripts/Adobe/adobe.bat /f"
    rem if %choice%==3 call "%cd%\scripts/Adobe/adobe.bat /a"
```

The adobe batch script needs a flag to run successfully, one of the following flags must be given: `/a,`, `/r`, `/f`

How can I run a batch script and a flag within a batch script?

What I've tried:

```
if %choice%==1 call "%adobe_path%\adobe.bat"
# this works but only outputs the help menu of the script

if %choice%==1 call "%adobe_path%\adobe.bat /r"
# this will output "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

cd "%adobe_path%\scripts\Adobe"
if %choice%==1 call "\.adobe /r"
# same as above

if %choice%==1 start "%adobe_path%\adobe /r"
# launches another cmd and won't run the script
```

Comment: Why not `call "%adobe_path%\adobe.bat" /r`?  `call` isn't limited to a single token.  The purpose of the quotation marks is to force `%adobe_path%\adobe.bat` to be evaluated as a single token in case the variable contains a space.  But `/r` would be the second token, and would be passed as the first argument to `adobe.bat`.

Comment: @rojo Yeah I'm an idiot lol. Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if %choice%==1 call "%adobe_path%\adobe.bat" /r
```

The executable (a batch file) is quoted to allow spaces in the name. The parameters are separated by spaces (or commas)